# Как легче всего распарсить xml документ?

Tags: php, xml, yii2

В данном случае получить список стран https://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/country-list/xml/. Может, в yii2 есть что-то для этого?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В php есть библиотека SimpleXML: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.simplexml.php

```
<?php
$filexml='http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/country-list/xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
$f = fopen('al.csv', 'w');
$country = $xml->country;
foreach ($xml->country as $country) {
    $vars_arr = get_object_vars($country);  
    $line_arr = array_values($vars_arr);
    fputcsv($f, $vars_arr, ',', '"');
}
fclose($f);
?>
```

Создает файл al.csv вида

```
Абхазия,"Республика Абхазия",Abkhazia,AB,ABH,895,Азия,Закавказье
Австралия," ",Australia,AU,AUS,036,Океания,"Австралия и Новая Зеландия"
```

Comment: Заменил $filexml='test.xml'; на $filexml=file_get_contents('https://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/country-list/xml/', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH); - ничего не произошло. print_r($xml); ничего не выводит.

Comment: Я думал, вопрос общего плана. Дал примерный код. Протестирую сейчас и исправлю.

Comment: Буду очень признателен, сам не пробовал работать с SimpleXML, так что не знаю, в чем тут тонкость. Сама библиотека подключена.

Comment: Сделал, проверил. Код рабочий.